# Bytes in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, char, byte, nslog

I am trying to declare a byte which I did in Visual C++ as this:

```
static CONST BYTE NEW_REGISTRATION              = 0x30;
```

but in Objective C I have done as thus:

```
const char  NEW_REGISTRATION                = 0x30; 
NSLog(@"output here = %C", NEW_REGISTRATION);
```

and my output seems to be just simply

output here = 0

### is it an encoding issue or am I getting the type wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ascii `0x30` represents `0` character. Try with something else e.g. `0x35`. See table: http://www.asciitable.com/